# How to upload an image that was pasted into TinyMCE after a ScreenShot?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins, tinyxml

Does anyone know how to upload an image that was pasted into TinyMCE after a ScreenShot?

Please can someone help me with an example in javascript?

I tried with multer, but not worked, because the Multer not filter a variable have texts and images, just must be variable with images without texts.

Answer (score 0):

By default, TinyMCE does not upload images on the server. It converts them into base64 and adds them as base64 blobs. To upload these images to the server, you will need to set up [automatic_uploads](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads) and add a custom upload handler (check other options in the configuration reference, like [images_upload_url](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url), [images_upload_base_path](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_base_path), [images_upload_credentials](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_credentials), etc).

Comment: Do you have an example with JavaScript? because in that tutorial is with PHP and is complicated to understand.

Comment: I only have this JS example of a handler that TinyMCE uses by default: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler
Hope it helps.